# Referring to outer scope variables in orderBy inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-orderby

I'd like to have an ng-repeat that's sorted by a value in some external lookup table.

For example, suppose I have a list of `items` with an `itemType` for each item. I have a separate `itemTypePriorities` lookup table in the scope, such that `itemTypePriorities[someItemType]` gives the priority for a given item type. Now, I'd like to display items in order of their priorities. I am trying the following:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:'itemTypePriorities[item.itemType]'>
```

But it doesn't seem to work - my guess is that it's interpreting the orderBy expression in the context of `item`, i.e. it's trying to order by the nonsensical expression `item.itemTypePriorities[item.itemType]`.

Is there a way to rewrite the ng-repeat to make it wok correctly, **without** having to modify the `items` or `itemTypePriorities` arrays in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use of course the orderBy filter but I think you will need to create a custom function to orderit.

For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | orderBy:myFunction>
```

Where myFunction is declared somewhere in your controller as:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(el){
    //el is the current element under evaluation
}
```

And should return a value that will be compared with <, === and > with the other. In your case the function can be:

```
$scope.myFunction = function(el){
    return itemTypePriorities.indexOf(el);
}
```

And that should work

Comment: Thanks - I also found the function solution but I'm trying to see if there's a way to avoid it. (In my actual use case, I need to sort by one more field in addition to the item priority, and the function approach doesn't work well for multi-field sorts)

Comment: I think the function approach is extremely powerful, because you can evaluate so much things for each element, the only thing is to return something that represent the order of the element. In my opinion I think that the function solution is longer, maybe more complicated, but usable for every situation, even in the hardest case.

Comment: Suppose you want to sort people (1) by name, (2) within people with the same name you want to sort them by bank account balance, and (3) if name and balance are the same, sort by 'itemPriority' lookup as above. What would your sort order function look like? I'm not convinced such a function even exists, especially if the balance is allowed to be arbitrarily large and arbitrarily precise. Remember that the orderBy function is not passed 2 objects and asked to compare them, but is passed 1 object and is asked to assign a value to it. So functional approach is limited when it comes to multifield.

Comment: then you should pass an array of functions, when a criteria is equivalent it will step to the next.
In your case you can also use string directly, just use ['name','balance','itemPriority'] (if those are the names of the fields) they will be evaluated waterfall

Comment: Hmm, I didn't notice in the orderBy docs that you can pass an array of functions. You're right then, function approach seems to be the way to go here. Still, it's unfortunate that Angular doesn't have a way to refer to "outside" variables in orderBy.